# Open Facebook Share Dialog with jQuery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I've a problem with jQuery click() function when I try to open the Facebook Share Dialog with this code:

```
 $(".like a").click(function (e) {
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

When I click the link it open a Share Dialog wthout text inside, no description, no title, no URL.
The same URL opened with this link work well:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Insert text or an image here.</a>
```

The PHP code that generate the parameters are this in both cases:

```
<?php 
$title=urlencode('Event'); 
$url=urlencode('http://www.my_site.com');
$summary=urlencode('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');
$image=urlencode('http://www.yourdomain.com/images/share-thumbnail.jpg');
?>
```

-------Update-----

Rendered code Javascript function:

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Event&amp;p[summary]=1+Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2C+consectetur+adipisicing+elit%2C+sed+do+eiusmod+tempor+incididunt+ut+labore+et+dolore+magna+aliqua.+Ut+enim+ad+minim+veniam%2C+quis+nostrud+exercitation+ullamco+laboris+nisi+ut+aliquip+ex+ea+commodo+consequat.+Duis+aute+irure+dolor+in+reprehenderit+in+voluptate+velit+esse+cillum+dolore+eu+fugiat+nulla+pariatur.+Excepteur+sint+occaecat+cupidatat+non+proident%2C+sunt+in+culpa+qui+officia+deserunt+mollit+anim+id+est+laborum.&amp;p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my_site.com&amp;p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourdomain.com%2Fimages%2Fshare-thumbnail.jpg','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
```

Rendered code onclick():

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Event&p[summary]=1+Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2C+consectetur+adipisicing+elit%2C+sed+do+eiusmod+tempor+incididunt+ut+labore+et+dolore+magna+aliqua.+Ut+enim+ad+minim+veniam%2C+quis+nostrud+exercitation+ullamco+laboris+nisi+ut+aliquip+ex+ea+commodo+consequat.+Duis+aute+irure+dolor+in+reprehenderit+in+voluptate+velit+esse+cillum+dolore+eu+fugiat+nulla+pariatur.+Excepteur+sint+occaecat+cupidatat+non+proident%2C+sunt+in+culpa+qui+officia+deserunt+mollit+anim+id+est+laborum.&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my_site.com&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourdomain.com%2Fimages%2Fshare-thumbnail.jpg','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"
```

Thanks to all for help

Comment: Have you checked your JS code that the client receives – are the values you are trying to output with PHP actually set in there?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered code?

Comment: I've added the rendered code. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an online example for both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Facebook sharer.php accepts query string parameters anymore.

It reads the open graph tags on the URL you're tring to share.

So make sure the URL your'e sharing has the proper og tags.

Comment: The only param you can pass is `u` the URL to share https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/

Comment: Sorry but if I try with same URL, with onclick() function, I have my personalized Share Dialog. It work correctly